# status code 400 bad request

Tags: rest, angular

I'm trying to use a rest service to for login page. But I'm getting this error status code 400 Bad request
This is my login service

```
    @Injectable()
    export class LoginService{
    constructor(private _http:Http){}
    postJSON(){
        var json = JSON.stringify({var1: 'username', var2: 'password'});
        var params = 'json =' +json;
        var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-type', 'application/json');
        return this._http.post('http://localhost:8080/login', params,{
            headers: headers
        }).map(res => res.json());
    }

}[This is my rest service][1]
```

This is my LoginComponent.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
  providers:[LoginService]
})
export class LoginComponent {
  postData: string;

  constructor(private _httpService: LoginService) {}
    OnTestLogin()
    {

      this._httpService.postJSON().subscribe(
          data => this.postData = JSON.stringify(data),
          error => alert(error),
          () => console.log("Finished")
      );
    }
  }
```

I'm very new to Angular and Rest services, why is it giving status code 400 bad request ?

Comment: a 4xx status code means, there is something wrong with the request. Check the server logs to find out why.

Comment: I don't get any server logs here. I am using post man for my service

Comment: Then double check the documentation of the API and compare it to what you send to the server.